# msgraph-sdk-go just responds with odata context, not the Data itself

Tags: go, sdk, odata, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-api

I want to Request a Calendar of a user using the Golang Graph SDK, but i just get random Odata Values as Response instead of Json or some other format.

First i made the Connection and Request using the official Docs and Issues on Github:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    azidentity "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    a "github.com/microsoft/kiota-authentication-azure-go"
    msgraphsdk "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go"
    cv "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/users/item/calendarview"
)

func main() {
    cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential(
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        nil,
    )
    auth, err := a.NewAzureIdentityAuthenticationProviderWithScopes(cred, []string{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"})

    adapter, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphRequestAdapter(auth)
    
    client := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(adapter)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Fehler: ", err)
    }
    requestStartDateTime := "2022-11-01T00:00:00"
    requestEndDateTime := "2022-11-17T00:00:00"
    query := cv.CalendarViewRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters{
        // Orderby: []string{"start/dateTime"},
        StartDateTime: &requestStartDateTime,
        EndDateTime: &requestEndDateTime,
        Select: []string{
            "subject",
            "start",
            "end",
        },
    }
    
    options := cv.CalendarViewRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration{
        QueryParameters: &query,
    }
    _ = options
    result, err := client.UsersById("redacted@domain.com").CalendarView().Get(context.Background(), &options)
    if err != nil {
        // const colorRed = "\033[0;31m"
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)

}
```

And i just get a response like that:

```
&{{map[@odata.context:0xc0002310d0] <nil> 0xc00043c030} [0xc0003da310 0xc0003da120 0xc0001daa11 0xc0001dad20 0xc0003dbf01 0xc0003db110 0xc0003da401 0xc0003db681 0xc0003da901 0xc0003daa81]}
```

I was expecting a Json output, not Random odata Context Values. is there something obvious that i have missed? The count of the Oxc.... Values changes, if i alter the StartDateTime and EndDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be accessing the `result` object as is as you are exposing the  internal `struct` response details without being able to navigate its properties properly.

You should retrieve the response using `GetValue` which would return a slice of `Eventable` objects over which you can iterate getting the desired *calendar* properties:

```
func main() {
    // code omitted as being unchanged
    // ...

    _ = options
    result, err := client.UsersById("redacted@domain.com").CalendarView().Get(context.Background(), &options)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, event := range result.GetValue() {
        iCalId := event.GetICalUId()
        startTime := event.GetStart()
        endTime := event.GetEnd()
        fmt.Printf("iCalId: %s | Time: (%s - %s) | \n", *iCalUId, *startTime.GetDateTime(), *endTime.GetDateTime()) // or any other properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Information from @tmarwen and added the Loop in another variation to my code:

```
    for _, event := range result.GetValue() {
    fmt.Printf("Subject: %s | Time: (%s - %s) | \n", *event.GetSubject(), *event.GetStart().GetDateTime(), *event.GetEnd().GetDateTime()) // or any other properties
}
```

Comment: The answer does not directly address the question asked.
Its added value is questionable

Comment: It does in Combination with the Answer from tmarven, since the code block did not work as he intended it.